# Updating ejs with data from database that's getting continuously updated

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, refresh, ejs

I have a query that gets run in my index.js file which loads the latest messages from the last two minutes, then that data gets put into an ejs file through the data array.

```
client.connect();
const query = client.query(new Query(`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE unix_timestamp > (${(Date.now()/1000) - 1800})`))

var data = [];
var total = 0;

query.on('row', (row) => {
  console.log(row);
  total += 1;
  data.push(row);
})
query.on('end', (res) => {
  console.log("this is the end");
  console.log("total is:", total);
})

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    data: data
  });
});
```

But I want to refresh the ejs page with any updates from the dashboard (so that messages look like they are coming in like a live feed), it doesn't necessarily have to be the last two minutes. Any idea how to accomplish this?

This is my ejs file:

```
<div>
  <% for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {%>
     <div class="tweet">
       <p class="tweetTime"><%= data[i].unix_timestamp%></p>
       <p class="tweetName"><%= data[i].screen_name%></p>
       <p class="tweetMessage"><%= data[i].cleaned_tweet%></p>
       <p class="tweetLocation"><%= data[i].user_location%></p>
     </div>
  <% } %>
</div>
```

Comment: You can do this with ajax?

Comment: And you dont need refresh the page with ajax?

Comment: Could you show me how to do this with ajax? I could really use some help